# Open source Test case management tool

Tags: testing, load-testing, functional-testing

I am looking for an open source test case management tool.
Is there anything which can take csv / xml / xls files and create test cases for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The free community edition of [Klaros Testmanagement](http://www.klaros-testmanagement.com/) has support for importing test cases from xls and XML.

It is not open source but free to use and not time or user crippled.

Disclaimer: Being involved in the development I am biased

Answer (score 2):

Recently found Nitrate\Kiwi, which is written in Python as Django app, may be interesting to take a look at https://github.com/kiwitcms/Kiwi

Comment: By any chance, do you have experience with using Kiwi TCMS through RPC API calls? It does not seem to work for me...

Comment: Yes, I've tried a few basic tasks in Kiwi using API. It works for me, it was somehow tricky with cookie stuff to keep user session, but in general it works for me with Python 3.6, xmlrpc lib and piece of code from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25876503/how-to-retain-cookies-for-xmlrpc-client-in-python-3/47291771#47291771