# How to retain cookies for xmlrpc.client in Python 3?

Tags: python, cookies, python-3.x, xmlrpclib

The default Python `xmlrpc.client.Transport` (can be used with `xmlrpc.client.ServerProxy`) does not retain cookies, which are sometimes needed for cookie based logins.

For example, the following proxy, when used with the TapaTalk API (for which the [`login` method](https://tapatalk.com/api/api_section.php?id=2#login) uses cookies for authentication), will give a permission error when trying to modify posts.

```
proxy = xmlrpc.client.ServerProxy(URL, xmlrpc.client.Transport())
```

There are [some solutions](http://www.lunch.org.uk/wiki/xmlrpccookies) for Python 2 on the net, but they aren't compatible with Python 3.

How can I use a `Transport` that retains cookies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple `Transport` subclass that will retain all cookies:

```
class CookiesTransport(xmlrpc.client.Transport):
"""A Transport subclass that retains cookies over its lifetime."""

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._cookies = []

    def send_headers(self, connection, headers):
        if self._cookies:
            connection.putheader("Cookie", "; ".join(self._cookies))
        super().send_headers(connection, headers)

    def parse_response(self, response):
        for header in response.msg.get_all("Set-Cookie"):
            cookie = header.split(";", 1)[0]
            self._cookies.append(cookie)
        return super().parse_response(response)
```

Usage:

```
proxy = xmlrpc.client.ServerProxy(URL, CookiesTransport())
```

Since `xmlrpc.client` in Python 3 has better suited hooks for this, it's much simpler than an equivalent Python 2 version.

Comment: Note that this snippet does not work as is. Because if server doesn't send cookie for some requests (example - there are cookies in response only after first "login" call and other responses do not contain them), it will fail trying to get_all("Set-Cookie"). So additional check is required here

Answer (score 6):

Existing answer from GermainZ works only for HTTP. After a lot of time fighting with it, there is HTTPS adaptation. Note the `context` option which is crucial.

```
class CookiesTransport(xmlrpc.client.SafeTransport):
    """A SafeTransport (HTTPS) subclass that retains cookies over its lifetime."""

    # Note context option - it's required for success
    def __init__(self, context=None):
        super().__init__(context=context)
        self._cookies = []

    def send_headers(self, connection, headers):
        if self._cookies:
            connection.putheader("Cookie", "; ".join(self._cookies))
        super().send_headers(connection, headers)

    def parse_response(self, response):
        # This check is required if in some responses we receive no cookies at all
        if response.msg.get_all("Set-Cookie"):
            for header in response.msg.get_all("Set-Cookie"):
                cookie = header.split(";", 1)[0]
                self._cookies.append(cookie)
        return super().parse_response(response)
```

The reason for it is that ServerProxy doesn't respect `context` option related to transport, if transport is specified, so we need to use it directly in Transport constructor.

Usage:

```
import xmlrpc.client
import ssl


transport = CookiesTransport(context=ssl._create_unverified_context())
# Note the closing slash in address as well, very important
server = xmlrpc.client.ServerProxy("https://<api_link>/", transport=transport)

# do stuff with server
server.myApiFunc({'param1': 'x', 'param2': 'y'})
```